# Customizing children components' styles through parent with JSS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm currently working on a project which has all of its styles declared in JSS. One of the "benefits" highlighted on many articles and the library docs is that it encapsulates styles. However I really am having a hard time customizing them, specially when it comes to styling that depends on the component's surrounding context (by context I mean parent elements, siblings, etc.).

Consider the following styles exported along a component called `FieldDescriptor` via the `withStyles` HOC:

```
info: {
fontFamily: theme.typography.fontFamily.light,
fontSize: "12px",
padding: "0 24px 8px 24px",
letterSpacing: 0.3,
```

},

This class will be found as `FieldDescriptor-info-xxx` on the element having that class. Now suppose that this component is child to another one that attempts to target the `error` class. You could target that class with something like `[class*=FieldDescriptor-error]` (personally I already consider this a very unclean approach) and it will work **only** on a development environment.

On production, classes will become unique (e.g. jss-xxx) and selectors like the one above will no longer be useful. My question is, what is the cleanest or "correct" approach to customizing component styles like this in JSS? I am either missing something really obvious or perhaps facing the limitations of JSS.

I am looking forward to solutions that do not require more tooling or code bloating, that would really miss the purpose of adopting JSS in the first place.

You can find an example using both `withStyles` and `useStyles` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/customizing-in-jss-material-ui-r7lko)

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of a component as of a black box that intentionally hides implementation details from the outside world.

With this model, only component itself is responsible for it's presentation, so you need to ask that component to change something. In React world you do that most of the time by passing props to that component.

Inside of that component you can go multiple ways, combining the predefined classes depending on the props (preferred because static) or using function rules/values which let you access the props and define the styles per component instance.